# Wordpress theme options cannot be read nor saved from/to database

Tags: wordpress, themes

We have installed this theme http://www.freshthemes.com/demo/weekly/ with WordPress 3.1.3.
When saving theme options the options are saved in the frontend, but not pushed through to the database.

On the front end, one can clearly see that the theme is still loading the correct values from the database.
That might have happened during one of the WordPress main version updates.

Any ideas about how to reconnect the admin panel to the actual option values (stored in wp_option)?
Maybe this happened due to a behaviour change in the WordPress core which is not reflected by the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_theme_mod-seems-not-returning-any-value-after-upgrading-tp-wordpress-31

More:
If your lost your theme options just have a look in the table wp_options and search for LIKE '%theme_mods_%' on option_name

In our case names changes like that:
OLD: theme_mods_weekly_v103 
NEW: theme_mods_Weekly

To restore the old settings copy the option_value to the new option_name